# redirect uri segment after delete

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I created a project , I have a question about the direct url segment ...

For example:
this my URL

**http://10.88.25.131/instrumentdev/instrument/instrument/detail/CT-BSC-001**

when I want delete the data and to direct to the url such as the example above

this my controllers

```
    public function detail(){

    $id = $this->uri->segment(4);

    $data = array(
                'detail'=>$this->mcrud->get_detail($id),
                'lihat' =>$this->mcrud->lihat_komentar($id),
                'isi'       =>'instrument/read_views');
    $this->load->view('layout/wrapper', $data);

    }

    function deletecom() {

    $u = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $this->mcrud->deletecomment($u);
    redirect('???**this my problem**???');
   }
```

Comment: what is your base url  ??

Comment: @BaDDeveloper, this my base url 

**http://10.88.25.131/instrumentdev**

Answer (score 1):

Use session

```
$newdata = array(
    'data'  => $u
);

$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
redirect('controller/method');
```

then in next method

```
$u = $this->session->userdata('data');
```

Comment: thanks but not running result, http://10.88.25.131/instrumentdev/instrument/instrument/detail/15         id CT-BSC-001 change 15

Comment: try `redirect('controller_name/method_name/$u');`

Comment: error "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters."

Comment: its same not running :( ,  please help me

Comment: @irwanDwiyanto what you doing with this ?? `$this->mcrud->deletecomment($u);`

Comment: okey this my methode i get detail   `public function detail(){
     
     $id = $this->uri->segment(4);

     $data = array(
                 'detail'=>$this->mcrud->get_detail($id),
     'lihat' =>$this->mcrud->lihat_komentar($id),
     'isi'    =>'instrument/read_views');
  $this->load->view('layout/wrapper', $data);
 }` this is model you want $this->mcrud->deletecomment($u)` `function deletecomment($a) {
  $this->db->delete('tbcoment', array('id_comment' => $a));
  return;
 }`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$this->load->helper('url');/*if not already*/
redirect(base_url('controller/method/parametersIfAny'));
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY this :

```
function deletecom() {
    echo $this->uri->segment(4);die();  //what does this print ?? 
    $u = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $this->mcrud->deletecomment($u);
    redirect(base_url('instrument/instrument/detail/'.$u));
   }
```

Comment: thanks but its not working the answer same @Moderation

Comment: can you check the `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] ` value in your `application/config/config.php` file ??

Comment: this the value `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';`

Comment: try changing it to this : `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z A-Z 0-9~%.:_\-';`

Comment: okay.. but result **http://10.88.25.131/instrumentdev/instrument/instrument/detail/27** blank